# Backbone Bind - Submit a Form while adding to DB and appending ItemView without Page Refresh?

Tags: backbone.js, express, mongoose, marionette

**What I Am Trying To Do**

I am trying to achieve the effect in the Backbone TodoMVC examples, in which the user submits an item and on submit the Item is appended to the collection view without page refresh. I am trying to do this, but also while submitting this data with a POST route to a db at the same time.

Example: (http://todomvc.com/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/)

Thanks

**What I Tried**

Reviewed several times, but i'm unable to isolate code how this bind/bindall effect works in BackboneJS.

**Currently Using**

NodeJs,

Express

Mongo/Mongoose/REST

Backbone/Backbone Marionette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting data to a DB has nothing to do with `bind`. `Bind` (and `bindAll`) are helper methods defined by underscore.js to set what object is referred to by `this` (see http://underscorejs.org/#bind). To learn more about the "problem" that `bind` solves, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this (paragraph "function context").

With that out of the way, to answer your question: all you need to do is save a new model instance. Backbone will save it on the server with a POST for you (if your `urlRoot` or `url` attribute is set up correctly). Then, you add the new model to the collection and Marionette's collection/composite view will add the item view for you automatically (see https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionview-automatic-rendering).

To achieve the same goal (create new model, then add it to the collection), you can use the `collection.create` shortcut. That's what's being used in the Todo code (lines 25-27): https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/js/TodoMVC.Layout.js#L25-L27

You can see another example from the code for my book here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L59

You'll notice that neither example uses `bind`.

Comment: I checked out your examples. Didn't think it was that easy. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. That's why Marionette is nice: a lot of things end up being pretty simple...